# Let $\zeta_n$ be the $n^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$. How can I prove that $\zeta_5\notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

This question is from Artin 15.3.3: Let $\zeta_n$ be the $n^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$. How can I prove that $\zeta_5\notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$? I'm quite stuck so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing $\zeta_5 \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263993/showing-zeta-5-notin-mathbbq-zeta-7)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What is the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7) : \mathbb{Q}]$?  What is the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5) : \mathbb{Q}]$?

Comment: oh I see! Thanks